# Mozilla's publicsuffix -- does it contains _all_ currently available LTD's?

Tags: validation, dns, mozilla, tld, public-suffix-list

There's a Mozilla's project "https://publicsuffix.org/". I think it'll come in handy for my library where I want to validate URIs, particularly the ltd part. Does publicsuffix contain *all possible ltd's in the word* which are currently available in the Internet and is always up to date? Can it be used in production?

Note that my question isn't about suggesting me a library or service for validating URIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this part from the documentation on the site you just linked to:

> Some people use the PSL to determine what is a valid domain name and
>   what isn't. This is dangerous, particularly in these days where new
>   gTLDs are arriving at a rapid pace, if your software does not
>   regularly receive PSL updates, because it will erroneously think new
>   gTLDs are not valid. The DNS is the proper source for this
>   information. If you must use it for this purpose, please do not bake
>   static copies of the PSL into your software with no update mechanism.

That's pretty much a "no" to your question, or at least a "maybe, if you're really careful".

If you want a list of all current TLDs, there is an authoritative list at https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt (it gets updated along with the root zone).